# My getcookie code does not work on iphones

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, cookies

I am driving crazy. My get function cookie code dose not work on iphones and iphones only it works fine with android and computers
can someone say this code below wont work ?

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

I have found this in w3schools as well

```
function userInfoFromCookies() {
  let name = "userInfo=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(";");
  for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === " ") {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
      return JSON.parse(c.substring(name.length, c.length));
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Someone said the problem is with the regular expression but how should I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the problem
the code is fine the only thing is to make sure the size of the cookie is not above the Iphone storage

If the size is above the Iphone storage it will render blank page
this problem is only on IOS and not androids